# How to use react-router-dom in server-side rendering in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

Using react-router-dom in server-side react creates an error.

```
Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM
```

I am using react-router-dom BrowserRouter to render my component in div if url match my component path.

```
  const routes = [

  { path: 'dashboard',
    exact: true,
    component: Dashboard
  },
  { path: 'notification',
    exact: true,
    component: Notification
  }

];
```

and then use this code to target specific div to render my component:

```
<div>
     { routes.map((route, index) => (
       <Route
            key={index}
            path={`${match.url}/${route.path}`}
            exact={route.exact}
              />
        ))}
</div>
```

But this code work only in client-side react. How can I implement this to server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering), you need to use different history provider for server side rendering because you don't have a real DOM (and browser's history) on server.

You may also want to use [memory history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) because it works fine on server side.

Comment: Hi sir. I tried your solution but  MemoryRouter only support one child element.

Comment: @JazulKerk you can easily wrap your routes into `<div>`. Actually router component can wrap your application's root element and it will be the only child element for it.

Comment: sorry I cant comprehend your explanation :( .  can you give me an actual code example for this? thank you.

Comment: @JazulKerk of course, please take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/FlyingDR/c00f2f3332f394818db9b7cc5b06bf32), hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed adding component to the Route.

```
<div>
         { routes.map((route, index) => (
           <Route
                key={index}
                path={`${match.url}/${route.path}`}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.component}
                  />
            ))}
    </div>
```